# creating a sphere iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the below code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sceneView = SCNView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(sceneView)

        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.scene = scene

        let camera = SCNCamera()
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: -3.0, y: 3.0, z: 3.0)

        let light = SCNLight()
        light.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = light
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 1.5, y: 1.5, z: 1.5)

        let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 5)

        let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)

        let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: sphereNode)
        constraint.gimbalLockEnabled = true
        cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]


        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

    }

}
```

The above does not display anything however it builds successfully.

When I change the line;

```
let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 5)
```

to (to create a cube):

```
let cubeGeometry = SCNBox(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, length: 1.0, chamferRadius: 0.0)
```

I am confused about how to make the sphere appear. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code actually did produce a sphere. The radius was too large and the camera happened to be inside the sphere!

Changing the radius from 5 to 0.5 did the trick!